# Cannot deploy sample GOLang application to Heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku, go

I tried deploying the sample GO application to Heroku listed [here](https://github.com/kr/go-heroku-example)

But when I run the command:

> git push heroku master

I get the following error:

Counting objects: 28, done.

> Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (28/28), 3.08 KiB, done. Total 28 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
>
> To git@heroku.com:mysterious-refuge-1227.git  ! [remote rejected]
>   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mysterious-refuge-1227.git'

The sample code might be out-of-date so I created a simple hello world GO App but from the same git push command I got the following error:

```
Counting objects: 10, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.16 MiB | 690 KiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Go app detected
-----> Installing Go 1.1... done
       Installing Virtualenv... done
       Installing Mercurial... done
       Installing Bazaar... done
-----> Running: go get -tags heroku ./...
package echo/...: unrecognized import path "echo/..."
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Go app

To git@heroku.com:evening-reef-1503.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:evening-reef-1503.git'
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Here is my system info:

- GoLang version: go version go1.1 linux/386
- Kubuntu version: 12.10

Comment: I assume you did not add the `Procfile` to your repo before pushing it.

Comment: The sample code in github has a Procfile. In my own app, I included a Procfile. I've verified that it has been added to my repo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect your original error is because you created the application with `heroku create`.  You're using Go, which is supported through a buildpack, so you should create the application with something like `heroku create -b https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git`.  I believe the demo app makes the same mistake - [my fork](https://github.com/jonmountjoy/go-heroku-example) fixes it - and I've submitted a pull request too.

Comment: You can also do this after the fact by running `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go`.

Comment: I'm still having an issue deploying Golang apps onto Heroku? Could somebody [please tell me what's wrong](https://github.com/Juicr/Juicr). I have my `Procfile` all nicely configured, and I've added the buildpack to Heroku (I can see it in the vars). However when I do a `heroku logs` I see: **bash: juicr: command not found** which implies that the `Procfile` command is incorrect. It may be worth noting that I'm deploying using Travis, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: How do you name a project ? Usually, you do : **heroku create projectName** . Here we get a random name . ex : stormy-lowlands-xxxx

Comment: Ok found it : **heroku create -b https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git projectName**

Comment: @RaymondChenon This is my first time.. I want to deploy the following go app to heroku, but I have no idea how to do it. I have read few articles, but I am still confused. Can you share the step by step process? https://github.com/target/goalert

Comment: @Umair This was more than 5 years ago :) . I checked tonight.

1 Clone then go to your repository ( `git clone github.com/target/goalert`  , then cd `goalert`)

2 The Golang heroku github was renamed. Command `heroku create -b https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go goalert-umair`  (goalert-umair is the project name ) . This command creates a git repository on heroku side with the remote named "heroku"

3 Now you have to push the code with `git push heroku master`.

It is deployed on https://goalert-umair.herokuapp.com/ . But the build fails and this is another story.