# Deploy heroku app not compatible with buildpack

Tags: go, heroku

When I try to deploy my app to heroku then I received:

> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git

The steps that I follow are:

1. as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16655766/4862911), I created a project on heroku by using `heroku create -b https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git` command
2. then I run `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go` command to set buildpack again

then I tried to `git push heroku master` but I receive `App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git` error

I also connected my GitHub account to heroku and tried deploy from master branch which was on GitHub. But I am still facing this error(App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git)

How to solve it?

Comment: And *does* your repo meet the requirements [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-support#activation)?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @blackgreen yes i already solved it but i dont remember how.

Comment: @blackgreen i will investigate it today and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is because you should not use your git url as buildpack. https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git is the default. Try this:

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:set mars/create-react-app
```